# Mirroring parts of repo guidance

Tags: git, github, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have two repositories. One for a local server at clients' home base and one for a cloud server. A lot of the code is exactly the same but some code just shouldn't be on the local server. Be it privacy reasons or just useless functions that wouldn't work.

As I set up my repository (Gitlab), I'm trying too make it so changes I've made to specific folders/components mirror across the different repo's.
I've thought about sub-modules but I've heard it has some limitations for using different branches other then master.

Thought I'd ask you guys what you think I should do in this sort of situation.

Here's a picture if that helps:

[image]